# Where are the power, ground and LED connections on this car air conditioning PCB?

Tags: power, led, pcb, ground, wiring

I ordered a PCB for my car air conditioning, as the old one was chewed off by rat. I lost the plug and I'm totally confused which wire would fit where. Can someone please help me in locating which pin is ground and power and LED?

PCB has 6 pins, so 6 wires to connect.

3 wires will work for a switch, LED and ground. So in total 2 switches, 2 LEDs and 2 grounds, making it 6 wires.

Below are pictures of the front and back of the PCB, and I would really appreciate help.

[image: PCB front]

[image: PCB back]

Comment: Best luck to find out pins is using digital multimeter probe function. Best guess is that top row first or second pin is GND (picture 1). Dark green is most common use for GND. However second picture contains black header so its not sure which one is correct one. GND pin does not have trace (light green)

Comment: Asking for an answer about the usage or repair of an undocumented product is not on topic here.  Practical you should pursue this with car-model-specific resources like a service manual or a photograph of a complete one.  The only way the question would really fit *here* is if you took the time to reverse engineer a complete circuit diagram of the board, but even then there aren't a lot of components that have meaningful polarities so it would take some theorizing about how it's even supposed to work - the board you have isn't really a complete system but part of a larger one.

Comment: It is very difficult even to make a guess without having this part on my hand in order to probe probing the tracks with a multimeter. Did you researched for schematics and service manuals? I suggest researching online forums of owners and repairers of the same model of car; usually, those folks have a lot information. Most of times, or all of times, the electric and electronic parts of a car should be repaired only by person who knows what they're doing and if needed they can find the correct procedures themselves. Be careful, because mistakes can cost you more than just the price of the part.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how auto repair is done.

The key is the wiring harness.  A lot of electronics people treat the harness as "just nothing", because it's "only wires"... but you want a reliable car, yes? Getting harnesses right is actually kind of hard. There's a lot to making harnesses reliable.

The gold-standard solution here is to go to a junkyard and get that entire wiring harness.  It probably contains 4-12 plugs and all the interconnecting wires.  Then you unplug all the plugs on your car, remove cable clamps and remove the harness carefully, removing components which may be in the way.   Then you swap in your replacement harness.

The brass-plated solution is to obtain from a scrap car the plug plus about 200mm of wire off a scrap car.  (or longer if that will allow a more durable place for the splices).  Then install competent splices on the 6 wires - this is usually pretty easy to match up since they will all be different colors or sizes.  The durability of this work (how soon before you have to in there to fix it again) will depend on how well you do the splices.  Barrel crimps are the cheap way.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. Mine is a very basic Tata Indica car in India. World doesnt even know a car like that exists. There is no possibility getting wire diagram, cant even find parts in scrap. I will try to patch pins to wires and plug on the black port in pic 2.